Can the POV Change
So my question is if my POV can change like from one character (Ajax) to another character (his sister Storm) but it has their name at the top of each chapter so no one gets confused. Can I do that? Just wanted to know before I continued on with chapter 4.

Check Writing a novel, can I do (this or that)?, Can other characters than the main character have point of view?, First person pov with more than one main chars,

How to execute a change of the POV in a first person novel POV?, and If a main character is writing the story, can I change who writes the story in the next chapter?. I'm sure you can find an answer under one of those questions. Or all of them.

Yes, you can use as many points of view as your story needs.  You can see examples of this in the Game of Thrones novels.  They shift the POV many times.
Changing the POV with each chapter is a normal tactic. Short of using an omniscient POV, keeping the same POV character for an entire scene is generally regarded as the minimum. But I’ve read novels by Ursula Leguin and Steven King that shift the POV more often.

Thanks. I asked up and reddit and got roasted for not reading much (I like set fantasy type stuff like PJO, WoF just to name a few) And it's just in different chapters I change the person who's POV it is.

Many very popular series actually do exactly what you describe (name at the top of the chapter) - see the Six of Crows trilogy for one that I particularly like. @SilverSkrill

Thanks. I didn't know if I could or not because I've seen it done in first person yet. Reddit ended up with me getting shamed and told me I need to stop being lazy and read more.

@SilverSkrill, while I disagree with the method, I can’t fault the advice.  The greatest teachers on writing are other writers. They teach us to read critically, to learn how to recognize why some writing works and other writing doesn’t. That’s how we learn to write better and better.

Yeah, the only issue is the books they said to read I can't in Australia or had... smut... in it and I'm a minor. They said better late than never.

@SilverSkrill, read any book you want.  read as many books as you can. compare the books you liked and those you didn’t to how writers create interesting and exciting scenex
